# ClassNotFoundException only after installing APK on my device

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the **.apk** from my app. I already ran it and debugged it, and It worked just fine, but when I tried to genrate the **apk** file and run it on my device, the app crashes. This is the same device I've used to run and debug the app on Android Studio.

This is the error when I debug only the apk file:

```
I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.com.clave, PID: 27029
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{app.com.appclave/app.com.appclave.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.com.appclave.SplashScreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.com.appclave-yXmYCRL4P7N4tjj38LZxFg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.com.appclave-yXmYCRL4P7N4tjj38LZxFg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.com.appclave.SplashScreenActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.com.appclave-yXmYCRL4P7N4tjj38LZxFg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.com.appclave-yXmYCRL4P7N4tjj38LZxFg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
Application terminated.
```

Also I found sometimes the problem is in the manifest.xml file but I already checked and my activity is there:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".infoAppActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".dudaActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TokenCodeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".informationApp" />
        <activity android:name=".NextTokenCodeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MultiDex issue: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41382641/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, specifically on API 26 (Android Oreo) because there are profiles in your device. The problem was that when you uninstall the first app, Android only uninstalled for the current user/profile.

The thing you should do is to remove the first application for all users.

[Uninstall for all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvUVE.png)

and that's it.